# Como selecionar todos os dados do BD e fazer uma contagem das palavras repetidas?

Tags: php

Bom, a parte do contar as palavras é relativamente fácil. Porem eu só consigo contar uma palavra por vez. Seria possível fazer uma analise completa no banco de dados e contar todas as palavras repetidas, e colocar o numero de vezes que ela é repetida ao lado da palavra?

Tipo, eu tenho 5 registros no banco de dados e quero analisar apenas a coluna TAGS

1º Registro : Php, Mysql, Java

2º Registro : MYSQL, Apostila, Java

3º Registro : Microsoft, C++, Java

4º Registro : C++, Apostila, Java

5º Registro : Apostila, Mysql, Java

Como resultado eu gostaria algo tipo assim :

Resultado da analise : Java (5); Mysql (3); Apostila (3); C++ (2); Microsoft (1);

Como se pode ver, no possível resultado, o código comparo todas as palavras existentes e conto as iguais, depois exibiu elas de uma forma "agrupada"

Comment: Ao invés de armazenar as tags separadas por virgula, melhor criar uma tabela `registro_tags`. Veja o exemplo: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4be7/3). Para separar esses dados será necessário uma função.

Comment: Esse tipo de operação é melhor realizada no banco de dados (com recursos como _full text search_). Fazendo puramente na sua aplicação PHP, você terá que ler todos os registros um a um e fazer essa checagem com as tradicionais funções para strings.

Comment: @luciorubeens crie uma resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que descreves pode ser realizado via MySQL sem recurso ao PHP.

Dada a forma como tens os registos, a minha sugestão é utilizar uma tabela temporária para inserir um registo para cada valor que se encontra separado por virgula e depois selecionar dessa tabela temporária com a contagem:

1. Simular a tua tabela:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE minhaTabela
       (`id` int, `nome` varchar(100), `tags` varchar(255))
   ;

   INSERT INTO minhaTabela
       (`id`, `nome`, `tags`)
   VALUES
       (1, "Gabe♦", 'Php, Mysql, Java'),
       (2, "bfavaretto♦", 'MYSQL, Apostila, Java'),
       (3, "utluiz♦", 'Microsoft, C++, Java'),
       (3, "John", 'C++, Apostila, Java'),
       (3, "Doe", 'Apostila, Mysql, Java')
   ;
   ```
2. Passar os valores para uma tabela temporária:

   ```sql
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (val CHAR(255));
   SET @S1 = CONCAT("INSERT INTO temp (val) VALUES ('",REPLACE((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `tags`) AS data FROM `minhaTabela`), ",", "'),('"),"');");
   PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s1;
   EXECUTE stmt1;
   ```
3. Selecionar as palavras e contar o número de ocorrências:

   ```sql
   SELECT val, count(*) FROM temp GROUP BY LOWER(TRIM(val));
   ```

**Resultado obtido:**

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bc72/7/0)

```
┌───────────┬──────────┐
│ val       │ count(*) │
├───────────┼──────────┤
│ Apostila  │    3     │
├───────────┼──────────┤
│ C++       │    2     │
├───────────┼──────────┤
│ Java      │    5     │
├───────────┼──────────┤
│ Microsoft │    1     │
├───────────┼──────────┤
│ Mysql     │    3     │
├───────────┼──────────┤
│ Php       │    1     │
└───────────┴──────────┘
```

---

Para utilizares no lado do PHP utilizando PDO:

```php
/* Dados da ligação à base de dados
 */
$dbcon = array(
    "host"     => 'localhost',
    "dbname"   => 'minhaBaseDados',
    "username" => 'utilizador',
    "password" => 'password'
);

/* Ligar à base de dados
 */
$dbh = new PDO(
    'mysql:host='.$dbcon['host'].';dbname='.$dbcon['dbname'].';',
    $dbcon['username'],
    $dbcon['password'],
    array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT               => false,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE                  => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND       => "SET NAMES utf8"
    )
);

/* Ler os dados para uma tabela temporária
 */
$sql = "
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (val CHAR(255));
SET @S1 = CONCAT(\"INSERT INTO temp (val) VALUES ('\",REPLACE((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `tags`) AS data FROM `minhaTabela`), \",\", \"'),('\"),\"');\");
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s1;
EXECUTE stmt1";

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$sth->closeCursor();

/* Recolher a informação
 */
$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT val, count(*) AS total FROM temp GROUP BY LOWER(TRIM(val))");
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

while ($row = $sth->fetch()) {
    echo '<p>A palavra '.$row->val.' está repetida '.$row->total.' '.($row->total==1?'vez':'vezes').'.</p>';
}

/* Matar a ligação e o script
 */
$dbh = null;
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponhamos que o array `$registros` sejam os registros que você puxou do banco. Criaremos um array `$tags` com a contagem para cada tag.

```
$tagCount = [];
foreach ($registros as registro) {
    $tags = explode(',', $registro['tags']);
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $tag = trim($tag);
        if (!isset($tagCount[$tag])) {
            $tagCount[$tag] = 0;
        }
        $tagCount[$tag]++;
    }
}
```

Depois é só ordenar:

```
usort($tagCount, function($a, $b) {
    return $a > $b;
} );
```